# Python: find for loop variable by inspection in called function

Tags: python, introspection

Is there a way to achieve something along the lines of the following in python:

```
def print_loop_var():
    loop_var = fn_inspect_frame_stack()
    print "The loop variable is: %s" % loop_var

for k in mylist1:
    print_loop_var()
    for m in mylist2:
        print_loop_var()
```

Output:

```
The loop variable is: k
The loop variable is: m
The loop variable is: m
...
The loop variable is: k
The loop variable is: m
The loop variable is: m
...
```

For my application, I cannot pass arguments to `print_loop_var()`.

Alternatively to the name, I would also be happy with the contents of the variable instead.

Comment: just curius, why you cant pass arguments to that function?

Comment: @DanielSanchez I am looking to define a Mako default filter that utilises the top-most loop variable for a particular code generation application.

Comment: how is `print_loop_var` supposed to know the name of the loop variable in its caller?   That's very restrictive ... "if you call me you must have a variable in your scope called `m`" ??

Comment: @donkopotamus "if you call me you must have a variable in your scope called `m`" - No: `print_loop_var` must find the name `m` by introspection or similar. `m` may have any other name!

Comment: @arf so instead you wish to have an implicit contract "if you call me you must have called me from inside a loop?"

Comment: @donkopotamus Indeed, that would be the idea. After some additional reflection I think there is no good way to achieve this. The solution would probably be to patch Mako instead.